# How to use Feign Client to upload multipart file?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have to make a call to upload a file to below service:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response uploadFile(
       @RequestParam(value="file", required=true) MultipartFile file, 
       @RequestParam(value="asOfDate" Date asOfDate,
       @RequestHeader(value = "metric") String metric,
       @RequestHeader(value = "user_id") String userId,
       @RequestHeader(value = "user_name") String userName,
       @RequestHeader(value = "user_company_id") String userCompanyId){
 }
```

As of now I am using RestTemplate to make a call to this service, but now I need to convert the RestTemplate calls to Feign Client.

I'm trying to accomplish a multipart file upload using feign, but I can't seem to find a good example of it anywhere.

Comment: Is it working without the feign client ? Make sure it is working for a regular HTTP Post possibly by adding a unit test to it.

Comment: Check [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752779/file-upload-using-feign-multipart-form-data) or [example](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/12/29/file-uploading-open-feign/)

Comment: @PrabinPaudel Yes it is working without feign client. I want to convert these calls to feign.

Comment: @AmitKBist these examples are not working, I am getting "Method has too many body parameters error".

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work

```
@FeignClient(
        url = "HOST_URL",
        name = "FileUploadClient")
public interface FileUploadClient {

@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response uploadFile(
       @PathVariable(value="file", required=true) MultipartFile file, 
       @RequestParam(value="asOfDate" Date asOfDate,
       @RequestHeader(value = "metric") String metric,
       @RequestHeader(value = "user_id") String userId,
       @RequestHeader(value = "user_name") String userName,
       @RequestHeader(value = "user_company_id") String userCompanyId){
 }
}
```