# Open Feign Java Document Upload Corrupting

Tags: java, netflix-feign, feign

I am having an issue with my open feign client uploading documents to a backend API.  I have been able to upload a document successfully using Postman, but when I use the exact same settings on my open feign client, the uploaded pdf becomes corrupted and cannot be opened.

```
  @RequestLine("POST /url")
  @Headers({
    "Content-type: x-www-form-urlencoded",
  })
  DocumentUpload uploadDocument(@Param("string") String string, @Param("file") File file);
```

The url, content type, and parameters are all the same in Postman, and as far as I can tell, there are no other settings that I am missing. Has anyone had similar issues or have ideas on what to troubleshoot?  Of note, I have tried different content types (eg multipart/form-data) and they fail similarly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752779/file-upload-using-feign-multipart-form-data especially "name" and content-type

Comment: Yes I saw that post previously when I was searching for answers.

Comment: As `string` is for the PDF file name only, the `file` is of interest. You need to access and check its content in both cases.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying.  That string param is just mocked in my example.  I have three string params in the actual code that specify things for the API I am talking to.  But I do not have a param for the actual filename.  Is that necessary somehow?

Comment: I must admit, that ot hers are more experienced with feign. Still no answer; good luck.