# OpenFeign Multipart Forms and @FeignClient

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, netflix-feign, feign

From Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752779/file-upload-using-feign-multipart-form-data), I've been trying to implement [Multipart File Uploading](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/12/29/file-uploading-open-feign/) using Open Feign.

The linked example uses an intermediate service to build the feign instance using Feign.builder.

I'd really rather wire this up using the @FeignClient annotation that the rest of my project uses. But when I try this I run into;

When using the @RequestLine style from the example

> Method uploadFile not annotated with HTTP method type

When using @PostMapping style

> Method has too many Parameters.

Comment: Did you include Multi-Part-support dependency. If you are using maven check Open Feign form.

Comment: @Mikjagger part of the problem seems to be mixing open feign and spring feign dependencies

Comment: @Jonita That could be the case have a closer look at the dependency tree.